# Why does this oracle bulk insert not work?

Tags: c#, oracle, bulkinsert, odp.net

I am trying to bulk insert some data into an oracle db. I followed the example in the documentation.

```
this.DataBaseAccess = new OracleConnection(connString);
var dataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter();
var insertCmd = DataBaseAccess.CreateCommand();
insertCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
insertCmd.BindByName = true;

var names = new List<string>();

foreach (DataTable table in product.Contracts.Tables)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        names.Add(row["Contract"].ToString());
    }

    const string InsertContracts = "merge into CONTRACT t " +
                                   "using " +
                                   "(select :name NAME from dual) s " +
                                   "on (t.NAME = s.NAME) " +
                                   "when not matched then " +
                                   "insert (t.NAME) " +
                                   "values (s.NAME)";

    insertCmd.CommandText = InsertContracts;
    insertCmd.ArrayBindCount = table.Rows.Count;
    insertCmd.Parameters.Add(":name", OracleDbType.Varchar2, names, ParameterDirection.Input);

    dataAdapter.InsertCommand = insertCmd;

    this.DataBaseAccess.Open();
    insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    this.DataBaseAccess.Close();
}
```

Well, it does not work. Nothing is inserted into the database, I don't get any error messages.

Everything works fine when i do not use bulk insert (instead i foreach-loop through each row from my DataTables and insert the DataRow into the Database on each iteration).

UPDATE: I have followed the suggestions and made the following changes to my parameter.

```
var nameParam = new OracleParameter
    {
        ParameterName = ":name",
        OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2,
        Value = names,
        Size = table.Rows.Count,
        CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray,
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    };
```

I get this error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Array'.
>      at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.SetStatus(Int32 arraySize)
>      at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.ResetCtx(Int32 arraySize)
>      at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.PreBind(OracleConnection conn, IntPtr errCtx, Int32 arraySize)
>      at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>      at Gateway.DataGateway.Import(String connString, Product product) in \path\share$\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ImportData-trunk\Gateway\DataGateway.Sql.cs:line 196

UPDATE2: The ODP.NET driver is stupid (just does not work as i exprected ;)

this does not work

```
var names = new List<string>();
```

it has to be this

```
var names = new string[table.Rows.Count];
```

Comment: Not sure why this doesn't work, but you should trying to a row by row insert first to see if that works.  Also, have you paid Oracle enough money?  That could be part of the problem.  ;)

Comment: It works row by row and my employer did pay oracle enough money ;)

Comment: that's just what happens when you have high exprectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to us the ToArray() method on the List.

```
insertCmd.Parameters.Add(":name", OracleDbType.Varchar2, names.ToArray(), ParameterDirection.Input);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the parameter `CollectionType` property to `OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray` to get bulk operations to work.

Since there's no `Add()` method that allows you to specificy this, you would have to add the following line after the call to `Parameters.Add()`:

```
insertCmd.Parameters[0].CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray
```

Comment: I tried you approach and ended with my update. it still does not work, but now I get an error message.

Comment: I am using ArrayBinding (execute the command x times, i give you all values before you start the execution). I do not need to use CollectionType or Size properties.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void BulkCopy(List<test_bulk> lsttest_bulk)
    {       
        try
        {
            //ConnectionString = String.Format("Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST={0})(PORT={1})))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME={2})));User Id={3};Password={4};", "ServerAddress", "PortAddress", "DatabaseName", "Username", "Password");

            ConnectionString = String.Format("Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST={0})(PORT={1})))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME={2})));User Id={3};Password={4};", "ServerAddress", "PortAddress", "DatabaseName", "Username", "Password");


            OracleConnection oraConn = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString);

            oraConn.Open();
            OracleCommand oraCMD = new OracleCommand();
            oraCMD.Connection = oraConn;



            var oracleBulkCopy = new OracleBulkCopy(oraConn)
            {
                DestinationTableName = "test_bulk",
                BulkCopyOptions = OracleBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction
            };

                DataTable oDataTable = GetDataTableFromObjects<test_bulk>(lsttest_bulk);

                oracleBulkCopy.WriteToServer(oDataTable);
                oracleBulkCopy.Dispose();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("failed to write:\t{0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }


    public static DataTable GetDataTableFromObjects<TDataClass>(List<TDataClass> dataList)
    where TDataClass : class
    {
        Type t = typeof(TDataClass);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable(t.Name);
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in t.GetProperties())
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(pi.Name));
        }
        if (dataList != null)
        {
            foreach (TDataClass item in dataList)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                {
                    dr[dc.ColumnName] =
                      item.GetType().GetProperty(dc.ColumnName).GetValue(item, null);
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
```