# Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Array' Oracle bulk insert

Tags: c#, oracle, bulkinsert, odp.net

I am trying to insert bulk data in Oracle Table but unfortunately getting this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Array'.

I have tried answers from these links but it is not working.

[why does this oracle bulk insert not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431208/why-does-this-oracle-bulk-insert-not-work)

[put your arrays in a bind](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/put-your-arrays-in-a-bind)

[bulk data insertion oracle](https://dzone.com/articles/bulk-data-insertion-oracle)

Here is my code:

```
private void InsertInTempMachineResults(ResultObject resultObject)
    {
        string command = @"INSERT INTO ANALYZERS.TEMP_MACHINE_RESULTS (SAMPLE_ID, TEST_ID, TEST_VALUES, " +
            "TEST_VALUES_SYMBOL, TEST_VALUE_UNIT, RESULT_DATE, STRING_ID, MACHINE_ID, PARSING_SOURCE) VALUES(" +
            ":sampleId, :testId, :testValue, :testValueSymbol, :testUnit, SYSDATE, :stringId, :machineId, " +
            ":parsingSource)";

        OracleCommand oracleCommand = new OracleCommand(command, Utils.Connection)
        {
            CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
        };

        oracleCommand.ArrayBindCount = resultObject.ResultItems.Count;
        oracleCommand.BindByName = true;
        OracleParameter[] parameters = {
            new OracleParameter("sampleId", resultObject.SampleId),
            new OracleParameter("testId", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 
                                resultObject.ResultItems.Select(r => r.TestId).ToArray(), ParameterDirection.Input),
            new OracleParameter("testValue", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 
                                resultObject.ResultItems.Select(r => r.TestValue).ToArray(), ParameterDirection.Input),
            new OracleParameter("testValueSymbol", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 
                                resultObject.ResultItems.Select(r => r.Symbol).ToArray(), ParameterDirection.Input),
            new OracleParameter("testUnit", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 
                                resultObject.ResultItems.Select(r => r.Unit).ToArray(), ParameterDirection.Input),
            new OracleParameter("stringId", OracleDbType.Varchar2, resultObject.StringId, ParameterDirection.Input),
            new OracleParameter("machineId", OracleDbType.Varchar2, resultObject.MachineId, ParameterDirection.Input),
            new OracleParameter("parsingSource", OracleDbType.Varchar2, "C#", ParameterDirection.Input),
        };
        oracleCommand.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
        if (Utils.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            Utils.Connection.Open();
        }
        try
        {
            int result = oracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (result <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR_INSERT_TEMP_MACHINE_RESULTS: {0}", "Unable to add data.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("EXCEPTION_INSERT_TEMP_MACHINE_RESULTS: {0}", e.Message);
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: `OracleDbType.Varchar2` means string, and you are passing arrays...

Comment: Where exactly does it throw that exception?

Comment: @PatrickHofman `Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Array'`

Comment: I asked *where*, I didn't ask to copy the error from the question...

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia You are correct but unfortunately, on every forum it is `OracleDbType.Varchar2`, as I have already posted links.

Comment: `int result = oracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: Are you sure not all parameters have to be arrays?

Comment: Yes I am sure! Only 4 parameters have to be arrays.

Comment: Does Oracle think the same?

Comment: @PatrickHofman You mean I have to convert all parameters to array?

Comment: Yes. I do......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **Patrick Hofman** suggested in comment, if you want batch insertion, you have to convert all parameters to Array. 
Problem Solved.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have converted all parameters to array its worked. Thank you so much.